# Retrieving view name property in android?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to retrieve the name of a view in android? Have been walking through the api and haven't seen any method to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Resource Name from Resource id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

View only contains id not name, I think it's not able to retrieve it.

From your comment, I think you can put the index to the android:tag attribute

such as

```
<RadioButton android:tag="1" />
```

Then you can invoke button.getTag to fetch the tag value. Hope this helps you get rid of the switch case statements..

Answer (score 9):

use `view.getId();`, which is usually used in `onClick(View v)` method

```
// from View.OnClickListener
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch( v.getId() ) {  // <= this is it
        case R.id.first_id:
         // do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is not a solution for me. I have a Radio group and each radio button name ends with a "index" in its name. I need to retrieve this to do some processing. I can't rely on the real radio button group index.

Comment: Post your code then, so we can think about solution for your case. This is common solution, looks like you're looking for something else.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about my problem, I think your solution could fit with some changes to my code. As an android newbie I was facing the problem from another point of view. Thanks.