# Android - how to get the name from resource?

Tags: android

I mean the name, not it's values, for example this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="magical_value_1">Lapin</string><br>
    <string name="magical_value_2">Poulet</string><br>
    <string name="magical_value_3">Saucisse</string><br>
</resources>
```

if i use `String value1 = getResources().getString(R.string.magical_value_1);`
the result it's going to be Lapin, but I need a way to get `"magical_value_1"` (not Lapin) in a variable. I need to do this because of languages, I have a lot languages in my app,and their values changes, but the name(magical_value_1) it's the only thing that remains(regardless the language). thanks

Comment: Did you read about supporting different languages http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html ? It sounds to me, that you're trying to support different languages, but is trying to do this the wrong way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id).

tl;dnr:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

Comment: in his case , what the `int resid` is for ?

Comment: He's asking how to convert the int value R.string.magical_value_1 into the string "magical_value_1".  That is why my answer does!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider take a look to [i18n](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) android developer documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying make your apps to support multiple language. Here's some simple sample.

Let's say you are trying to make your apps to support france and english. You needs to create **res/values/strings.xml** for english (Be precisely, other language then france) and **res/values-fr/strings.xml** for france.

Inside res/values-fr/string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="magical_value_1">Lapin</string><br>
    <string name="magical_value_2">Poulet</string><br>
    <string name="magical_value_3">Saucisse</string><br>
</resources>
```

And inside res/values/string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="magical_value_1">Rabbit</string><br>
    <string name="magical_value_2">Chicken</string><br>
    <string name="magical_value_3">Sausage</string><br>
</resources>
```

To test it by changing your device language on settings.

Comment: that is what i do, but not sure when I change a language different than english , doesn't work , but I have fixed now