# String value to a variable

Tags: java, android, string

this is a question about java on android - eclipse 
I have a `String` r
for the record, I defind him like that:

```
String r="pic"+c1;
```

I want to take the value of it, which is "pic6" and use it as a variable name.

how do I do it?

Comment: If c1 is 6 what is wrong with concatenation?

Comment: Dynamic variables are not supported in Java.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pick an image with name "pic6.png" from the drawable folder of the Android application, you can try the following code.

```
String r = "pic" + c1;

int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(r, "drawable", getPackageName());
if (resId != 0) {
    imageView.setImageResource(resId);
} else {
    // This is used in case no image resource is found
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknown);
}
```

Please see: If you use the else part, then you need to add "unknown.png" image to the drawable folder of the Android project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly but you could use a HashMap to emulate what you seek.

Example:

```
String r="pic"+c1;
HashMap<String,Integer> extendedVars=new HashMap<>();
extendedVars.put(r,10);
```

Comment: sorry, I dont know what HashMap is...
I have this code: 
`String r="pic"+c1;
pic6.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
      R.drawable.orange));`
I want to put r instead of pic6.

Comment: @AlonLousky A map maps keys to values, so you can use it to emulate dynamic variable declaration (say you later write an interpreter). 

You could say HashMap<String,'type'> varMap=new HashMap<>(); varMap.put("pic6", new ...); then later call varMap.get("pic"+c1).setImageDrawable(.....)

Comment: @AlonLousky Considering this is an Android question (didn't notice that in my original answer), you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-ressource-name/3476470#3476470

Comment: great, it very helped me. thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Like Eng. Fouad said. Dynamic variables are not supported in Java. 
Same question can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/dynamic-variable-names-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

In java, variable names must be known in compile time. There is no way to do what you are trying to do.