# In Android, how do I refer to a specific image under drawable folder if the image I wish to refer to from another activity

Tags: java, android, imageview, drawable

For example, the name of the image is got from the following code

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String name = bundle.getString("Name");
```

And what i would like to do is like

```
int picId = R.drawable.name;
```

where name should be replaced by the actual name. How can I do that? Or is there an alternative way so that I could show the picture in ImageView? I tried to put the image in the database which worked, but it makes the database way too large.

Comment: Why not passing the integer reference to the drawable using the Bundle, instead of a String ? It would certainly make things a lot easier...

Comment: Please check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724094/string-value-to-a-varaiable/19724382#19724382

Comment: thank you,will you please mark my answer as correct one

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 String name = bundle.getString("Name");

 int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
```