# Get the string id of a button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, radio-button

my button has a string id

```
<RadioButton 
android:id="@+id/Dirty" 
android:text="Very Dirty"
```

and I would like to use the name Dirty in my code but I cant use get Text since the display name of the radio button is different from what I need and get Id returns an integer.

Any suggestions on how to get the "Dirty" from my selected radio button?

Thanks.

***Code (from comments)***

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId); 
String sel = (String) rb.getText();
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
String sel = (String) rb.getText();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int selectedRdBtnId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedRdBtnId);
String rbText = radioButton.getText();
```

Edit:

For getting id, I would suggest implementing onCheckedChangeListener.

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int radioButtonID) {
       //radioButtonID contains selected radio button's ID.

       case R.id.dirty:
           //do something
           break;
       case R.id.clean:
           //something else
           break;
       default:
           //default action
           break;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the getText just returns the display name of the button and not the id name of the button.

Comment: The thing is that I know which radio button is selected and I can get the id but the id will always return an integer. I need the string name I gave to the button as an id.

Answer (score 6):

Use [getResourceEntryName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) method :

```
    RadioButton myButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    String s = myButton.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

for getting name of a component use getName() . I think this will help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
set tag to your radio button and get that tag in you java class

Xml

```
android:tag="Dirty"
```

Src

```
rb.getTag().toString();
```

Comment: the getText just returns the display name of the button and not the id name of the button.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to add a tag with the same name as id to your radio button (in addition to id):

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/Dirty"
    android:tag="Dirty"
    android:text="Very Dirty"
    />
```

Then in your code you can get the tag as String:

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Dirty);
String tag = (String) radioButton.getTag();
```

So the inconvenience would be to add tags to your radio buttons, which are the same as their id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a string to refer at your button, you should use `Tag` instead of `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id).

This one

```
getResources().getResourceName(int resid);
```

seems to be useful for you.