# how to get the location of the layout "R.Layou.*" if the id is given in the form of integer like "2131296340"

Tags: java, android, reference

I am not getting to how to know to which layout it is point because instead of giving the full name like `r.layout.activity_main` it has given the id in the form of integer.

How to get the location if the integer id is given how to convert it?

Comment: **"...it has given the id in the form of integer."** : I don't understand what you mean. What *exactly* has given the id as an integer? All resource ids are integers.

Comment: i want know the actual path id like r.layout.id instead of resource how to convert it nd where to put the code

Answer (score 0):

use

```
getResources().getResourceName(int resid);
```

read more in that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138018/2619921)

Comment: where should i use this line getResources().getResourceName(int resid) i means where should i put this code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the full id like `R.id.your_id` you have to make two calls:

- `getActivity().getResources().getResourceEntryName(int);`
  Which returns the identifier `your_id`
- `getActivity().getResources().getResourceTypeName(int);`
  Which returns the type of the resource like `id`, `string`, `layout`

As a note: Make sure the id with the corresponding value exists! Otherwise you will get a `NotFoundException`.

Comment: I did this in a Fragment, that's why I use getActivity(). To use it in your Activity get rid of the getActivity() call. If you wanna call it in a custom class pass a valid context and call: context.getResources()...