# Android Java getId() name not int value

Tags: android, integer

Lets say i have a few views and I want to get the id name of their IDs

view.getId()
returns an int value but instead i want to get the name of the id

android:id="@+id/valueFrance"

So is there any method on java that can return the name/value of the id ( "valueFrance" ) ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id ,where resid is the id you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

Comment: resid will be view.getId()

Comment: thanks i already did so :)