# Get resource name including configuration qualifier from resource id

Tags: android, android-resources, configuration-qualifier

You can get the resource name as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138018/1489968

But unfortunately `getResourceEntryName(R.layout.xzy)` is returning `xyz` and `getResourceName(R.layout.xzy)` is returning `package:layout/xyz`.

Is there any function that returns the active configuration qualifier for a given resource id using the [best match algorithm](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)?

For my test I need the following information:

- resource type (e.g. `layout`)
- active configuration qualifier (e.g. `-v21`)
- (or better both of them combined like `layout-v21`)
- resource identifier (e.g. `xyz`)

I found [Resources.getConfiguration()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getConfiguration()) that seem to give me a configuration. But I can't figure out a way to get the selector for a given id.