# How do I get the resource name of an image if I know its resource id?

Tags: android

I know how to get the resource id using of resource name.

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Now I want to know how to get the name of resource using of it's id? Is it possible to get the name of the resource using ID?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10138018/833647

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id

Comment: Why do you need this? You can findViewById using the int id that is returned here

Comment: Also, you already have `name`....

Comment: I am facing some issue while upgrade my app. I don't know how to fully explain my case. But I need this for solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. :-)

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of the actual problem? Are you trying to dynamically access resources without going through R.java like R.drawable.name?

Comment: @Vijay Are you decompiling the apk?

Comment: No @KNeerajLal.. We release a app to our client. Now we give another update to them. Unfortunately the resource id are changed. So that we face some crash issues. To avoid that we planned to get the resource name using of id and that we do some logics to change the resource. I don't know how to explain this clearly. Sorry..!!