# Android recognize if resource id is drawable or string

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I would like to know if it is possible to recognize, if **id** is from `drawable` or `strings` resource.

For example: 
If I call `R.strings.hello` that return `int` value `2131099681.

Can i recognize that the **id** is from **strings** folder?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I need to know what to display on screen. If is it image i display image and if is it string I display text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use (in activity)

```
getResources().getResourceTypeName(int resid);
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138018/4714139)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
Resources.getResourceTypeName(int resid)
```

Docs [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceTypeName%28int%29)

Comment: It is not a static method. So please look at it.

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak That's what docs are for, SO philoshopy is not to give code ready to use but hints