# Convert int Id of a View to its string resource name?

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose I define a `View` with an `Id` like this, in an Android XML layout file:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/my_view_id"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

In Java code, I can retrieve the Id of the View as an `int`, like this:

```
int id = view.getId(); // This returns something like 234567890
```

But I cannot tell what this object is from the number only, so I want to read the String representation of the int, like `"my_view_id"`, as per the original XML file.

Is there a way to do this? Can I convert the `int id` to a human-readable name of the id?

Comment: What do you mean by human readability?

Comment: Can you please expand what you are talking about?

Comment: Please provide a complete example. What exactly are you trying to do here? How will the "human readable id" be used?

Comment: in what language or using what library for a specific language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Resource Name from Resource id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id)

Comment: I update my question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for @David Medenjak this is Answer

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

Comment: There is also `getResources().getResourceName()` which will return the full package name, like `"com.company.MyApp:id/button_login"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this as far as I know. If you want to get the string you used in "@+id/myviewid", you could do something like android:tag="myviewid". This will store your view id name in the views tag, which can be accessed via view.getTag().