# Is there a way to programmatically get the id of an attribute?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get the id of an attribute programmatically, for example:

`val attr = R.attr.textAppearanceHeadline1`

Is there anyway to get "textApperanceHeadline1" (the name of the attribute reference) from the variable `attr`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id

Comment: Thanks for the link, exactly what I was looking for!