# How to get drawable with hexadecimal ID in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, drawable

I got a Resource Not Found exception, but I do not know which drawable causes. Because, the app is in publish and I saw this error on Firebase crashlytics. This is run time error and this crash occurs on only one device - Nexus 5X (Android Version: 8.1.0)

Firebase says
`Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08029f`

And, I want to find the drawable by this hexadecimal Resource ID. Is it possible? If it is, can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Resource id seems to be generated when the app compiles. So if you are going to recompile your app and print some debug log to find out the resource, it seems not possible to do so.

Comment: Also, this may due to the resource is not shared among all device resolution.
For example, you put a.png in a xxxhdpi folder, but the actual device is a xhdpi. At the sametime, you haven't put a default a.png in the origin drawable folder, this will lead to the problem.

Comment: And if you want to find out the which resources w/o looking in the folders, you will need to printout the corresponding resource name before you load the resources. REF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137692/how-to-get-resource-name-from-resource-id

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA thank you so much, putting default drawables is so meaningful, and I found that, some png files are only in xhdpi and etc. I will put their defaults, too. Thanks again